# How to run a .py model in Google Colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, github, google-colaboratory

To preface this, I am a complete beginner at ML and I'm trying to run a model from a Github repo in Colab. The model has a lot of different folders/modules and I've been attempting different methods of either cloning the repo, directly uploading the files and other methods I've found online. The model contains many folders and .py files which rely on the folders, so I'm not sure if the various paths using the os library will work. Any advice on how to set up and run a model in Colab? Thank you!

Edit: to be more specific, I want to be able to call my file that runs the model

```
python model.py
```

and run it using Colab's GPU. I'm getting a little confused as to how to set this up (I think I might need to mount it but I haven't figured it out). Within model.py, I have imports calling to other folders in the repo, so I'm also not sure if this will work in Colab i.e.

```
from otherfolder import ....
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is too broad to get good quality answers without a huge amount of work by the answerers to anticipate all possible issues with migration to collab. Please share a specific code snippet from the model which you are having trouble with, then we can give you specific answers.

Comment: Hello! I have tried to edit my post to be more specific. Thank you for letting me know!